# How to run a saved tensorflow model in the browser?

Tags: tensorflow, javascript

After doing my hello world models, I would like to let them available at Github pages, which means that I need to serve the model only with static files. Is it possible?

All the tutorials I found requires nodejs or some backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find **exactly** that [at this site](https://carlos-aguayo.github.io/tfjs.html), which offers a handwritten digit recognizer as a static site served from github pages.

[Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-a-simple-machine-learning-model-into-a-webapp-using-tensorflow-js-3609c297fb04) you can find the article describing how the author did it. You can also have a look at the [github repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-website) or directly the [html file](https://github.com/carlos-aguayo/carlos-aguayo.github.io/blob/master/tfjs.html) to understand the how it works. The author also released the [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/carlos-aguayo/e56a341190c4a252c4f66289b9228a69/mnist-on-gpu.ipynb) used to train the model.